# How to rearrange subplots so that one is underneath the other?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I am trying to code two plots such that one plot is underneath the other. However, my code keeps aligning my two plots next to one another. 
This is my code:

```html
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from numpy import sin, cos, pi, array
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import rcParams
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import figure, axes, title, show
import xlsxwriter

plt.style.use('ggplot')

def deriv(z, t):
    l = 0.25    #unextended length of the spring, in m
    m = 0.25       #mass of the bob, in kg
    k = 29.43      #spring constant, in Nm^-1
    g = 9.81    #gravitational acceleration, in ms^-2
    
    x, y, dxdt, dydt = z
    
    dx2dt2 = (l+x)*(dydt)**2 - k/m*x + g*cos(y)
    dy2dt2 = (-g*sin(y) - 2*(dxdt)*(dydt))/(l+x)
            #equations of motion
    
    return np.array([dxdt, dydt, dx2dt2, dy2dt2])


init = array([0, pi/2, 0, 0])
            #initial conditions (x, y, xdot, ydot)

time = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
            #time intervals (start, end, number of intervals)

sol = odeint(deriv, init, time)
            #solving the equations of motion

x = sol[:,0]
y = sol[:,1]

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharex=True)

ax1.plot(time,x)
ax1.set_ylabel('hi')

ax2.plot(time,y)
ax2.set_ylabel('fds')

plt.plot()
```

but I keep getting this as a result:
[image]

I have tried:

```html
plt.subplot(x)
plt.subplot(y)
plt.show()
```

but I run into this error:

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cnoxon/Desktop/Python/Final code 2 copy 2.py", line 39, in <module>
    plt.subplot(x)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 1084, in subplot
    a = fig.add_subplot(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1367, in add_subplot
    a = subplot_class_factory(projection_class)(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_subplots.py", line 39, in __init__
    s = str(int(args[0]))
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
>>>
```

How should I go about solving either of these problems? Alternative solutions are equally appreciated - I have no preference as to how the plots are created; I just want one to be under the other. Thank you!

Comment: Your call `plt.subplots(1, 2, sharex=True)` says to plot side by side (1 row, 2 columns), simply flip the `nrows` and `ncols` arguments to `plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True)` (2 rows, 1 column).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way the numbers work in [subplots](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) is that first you provide the number of rows and then the number of columns. To have plots below each other, you need 2 rows and 1 column. Hence you first have to write 2 and then 1 in `plt.subplots(2, 1)`

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True)
```

From the official docs

> matplotlib.pyplot.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, sharex=False, sharey=False, squeeze=True, subplot_kw=None, gridspec_kw=None, **fig_kw)

The way you have it right now is 1 row and 2 columns, which is why you see them next to each others.

**Second way** is using `subplot` where `211` means a figure with 2 rows, 1 column and 1st subplot and `212` means 2 rows, 1 column and second subplot. So the first two digits specify the number of rows and columns and the third digit specifies the subplot number.

```
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(time,x)
plt.ylabel('hi')

plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot(time,y)
plt.ylabel('fds')
```

[image]